# Who sells Pharros Lockstones in Dark Souls 2?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I would like to know who sells pharros lockstones in Dark Souls 2? (Except Melentia that sells only one of them.)

Answer (score 4):

The only person that sells Pharros Lockstones is Melentia. All other lockstones can be found on corpses or dropped from certain enemies.

[The wiki](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Pharros'+Lockstone) has a full list of these locations.

Additionally (thanks to DoubleDouble) if you join the Rat Covenant, you can get Pharros Lockstones by defeating other players dragged into your world, or by killing a member of the Rat Covenant when you are dragged into theirs.

Comment: The Rat King Covenant, upon defeating a player dragged into your world, also gives Pharros lockstones. (Or if you win against someone in the covenant)